# Keyboard scancodes?

Tags: linux, text, console

GNU/Linux text console, X11 not involved, indeed not even
installed. Keyboard is US layout, keymap US default. Kernel
version 2.20.x or later.

An application written in C is getting keyboard input in
translation mode, i.e. `XLATE` or `UNICODE`. When a key is
pressed, the application receives the corresponding
keystring. As an example, you press F1, the application
reads `"\033[[A"`.

Before the kernel sends the keystring to the application, it
must know which key is pressed, i.e. it must know its
scancode. In the F1 example above, the scancode for the key
pressed is 59 or 0x3b.

That's to say even when the keyboard is in translation mode,
the scancodes are held somewhere in memory. How can the
application access them without switching the keyboard to
`RAW` or `MEDIUMRAW` mode? A code snippet would help.

Answer (score 2):

Chances are that you are issuing the ioctl commands on the wrong file descriptor, check for error codes coming back from ioctl and tcsetattr.

You should be opening the console device, and then issuing your keyboard translation commands on that device.   You would have to basically mimic what the X server is doing.

This is a link to the source code on [codesearch.google.com](http://tinyurl.com/5yd92j).

Comment: Could you please replace the tinyurl with the real url? The specified tinyurl does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, the code you want to look at is in kbd-1.12.tar.bz2, which is the source bundle for the 'kbd' package. The 'kbd' package provides tools such as 'dumpkeys', 'showkeys' and 'loadkeys', which are useful for looking at the current keyboard mapping, checking what keys emit what scancodes, and loading a new mapping.

You will have to communicate with the kernel via ioctls, and it's quite complicated, so I recommend reading the source of that package to see how it's done.

Here's a link to the tarball: [kbd-1.12.tar.bz2 (618K)](ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kbd/kbd-1.12.tar.bz2).

Answer (score 0):

At a terminal I entered

```
dumpkeys -f > test.txt
```

and there was a great deal of detailed information, including:

> keycode  29 = Control
>   ...
>   string F1 = "\033[[A"
>   string F2 = "\033[[B"
>   string F3 = "\033[[C"
>   string F4 = "\033[[D"
>   string F5 = "\033[[E"
>   string F6 = "\033[17~"
>   string F7 = "\033[18~"
>   string F8 = "\033[19~"
>   ...
>   string Prior = "\033[5~"
>   string Next = "\033[6~"
>   string Macro = "\033[M"
>   string Pause = "\033[P"

dumpkeys was included by default with my distribution. But you should be able to find it in what jerub posted. I would start by looking `kbd-1.12/src/loadkeys.y`.

It looks like the kernel is responsible for holding that data, and can report to those who know how to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe want to look at `kbdev` or `evdev` (look at your `Documentation/input/input.txt` file in your kernel source directory for starters.)  That would work for console access.